# conv2d and conv2d_transpose with stride=1

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

Is working of conv2d_transpose with stride=1 same as conv2d layer? Since there is no upscaling done if stride=1 so can the result produced by conv2d_transpose layer be the same as that by conv2d layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as long as the padding is also correct, you can see clear examples [here](https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic) but I'll refer two to demonstrate (Blue is input, green is output, 3x3 conv):

- Convolution, same padding, no strides:

[image]

- Transposed convolution, same padding, no strides:

[image]

As you can see, they are the same.

But check what happens if we have the transposed convolution with no padding and no strides:
[image]

So I'd say it's depending on both, padding and strides to be the same that a conv.
If you want a in depth description of transposed convolution layers check [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers).